# Best way to "cache" Eloquent queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have an application that runs function like `SomeModel::getValue($month, $year, $departmentId)` in a loop.

`getValue` creates a query and returns the result:

```
return self::where('department_id', '=', $department_id)
           ->where('year', '=', $year)
           ->where('month', '=', $month)
           ->pluck('value');
```

In this loop it might call the same arguments more than once.
I wanted to know the best way to avoid creating a new query each time i want to get the data.

I thought about creating a static array inside the model and match against it every time `getValue` is being called. If value exists in the array just return it, if not create a query.

Is my solution ok? you have any other ideas? thank you!

I'm using Laravel 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static caching is the best method as long as you are ok with the implications:

- You only cache per request -- if the user refreshes, you recreate the cache from scratch
- You will have some memory overhead to keep the populated static array. This, on its own, is not a big deal until you have to take into account concurrency (each request has its own static arrays).

Depending on the maximum size of the static array, it might be best to decide how long your cache is valid for (eg 1 minute), and push the cache to some form of cross-request cache so that you can reuse it ( see APC, Memcached, or even simple MySQL INSERT in a table) -- in all cases just save the serialized array and load it as an additional step before doing the actual computation.

Comment: Note that APC and Memcached also make use off php serialize and unserialize too store Arrays and Objects, floats, ints and strings will not be serialized, this can boost up CPU load if you store large Arrays or Objects.

Comment: Didn't want to elaborate much on that, since the original question is about static caching, but yes - assuming you want to use any cross-request cache, depending on size and other constraints it is best to split it into many small chunks instead of a huge one, eg 1 entry per array item if the array is huge.

Comment: Hey thanks. Main goal here is run a query once for the same params. I guess I'll go with the static array inside the model since the array will not include more than 100 items